# How can we generate a sub menu context dynamically for a treeviewer

Tags: java, contextmenu, e4, treeviewer

I have populated a context menu for a treeviewer but now i need to dynamically populate the submenu context for the treeviewer the sub context menu shold contain all the contents in the list.for eg the list contains [a,b,c,d,e] so now main menu has menu A and the submenu must contain all the elements in the list can this be done

the menu structure should be as follows
A->a
   b
   c
   d
   e

Now the code for context menu is as follows

```
protected void fillContextMenu(final IMenuManager contextMenu) {
        //String nnn = null;
        //contextMenu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
        //contextMenu.add(new GroupMarker(nnn));

         IMenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Add Test Case");

            submenu.add(new Action("Sub menu item 1") {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     // implement this
                 }
             });

           contextMenu.add(submenu);



        contextMenu.add(new Action("Add Test step") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // don't do anything here
            }
        });
        contextMenu.add(new Action("Add New Test Case") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // implement this
            }


        });

}
```

So now how can we generate the dynamic  sub context menu contained in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that

```
IMenuManager.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
```

is called when you create the context menu. This means that `fillContextMenu` will be called each time the menu is shown.

Then all you need to do is loop through the list creating actions for each item in the list in `fillContextMenu`:

```
List<String> itemList = .... your list

for (String item : itemList)
 {
   submenu.add(new Action(item) {
         @Override
         public void run() {
               // implement this
         }
   });
 }
```

Comment: when i press any button in the submenu how can i get the name of the submenu which is pressed

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments